# How to use django as backend for cordova?

Tags: django, cordova, backend

Not a web developer, but currently playing with `cordova` and would like to use `django` to use python to implement backend functionality. As I (vaguely) understand it, cordova manages frontend stuff and django is mostly for backend stuff. So is it possible to use django as a backend for a cordova project (eg. directly use preexisting django templates in a cordova app)? If so, how? Is there some kind of special communicationn that I'd need to code myself?

(My uneducated guess would be to initialize the django project inside the cordova www folder, but this seems wrong). And if this is a totally wrong way to think about this problem, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Django as your backend and implement a REST like API (urls that accept and return JSON data) in it. There are useful tools/libraries for that, for example [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Then you would call those endpoints (URLs) from your frontend, which can be written in `cordova` or any other JS frontend frameworks.

As you already pointed out, I suggest keeping frontend and backend code in separate folders.

Comment: I see, some further googling (https://www.quora.com/Do-you-need-a-backend-with-Apache-Cordova/answer/Ziya-Pathan-1, https://www.studytonight.com/apache-cordova/connection-with-backened) seems to indicate that _http requests_ are indeed the standard way to implement this kind of thing. Will wait the traditional 48 hours and accept this answer.

Comment: Further, I assume that this means that it would basically be not possible to directly use preexisting django templates as  www resources for a cordova app, correct?

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter yes, HTTP requests (sent from cordova frontend to the django backend) are the way to go. And also yes, you would **NOT** use any django templates in that case.